# Woocommerce template file outputting <strong><code> tags

Tags: php, customization, code

I'm struggling with the editing of the woocommerce template files. In particular, I'm trying to create a custom cart page and, as guidelines, I've copied the cart.php template file to my template folder. However, any html that I write gets enclosed in

```
<strong><code></code></strong>
```

tags. I really don't understand why, does anybody have an idea?

Here's an example:

```
<?php defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' ); ?>
<div><span>hello</span></div>
```

It outputs

```
<strong><code><div><span>hello</span></div></code></strong>
```

Comment: You probably have an unclosed <strong> tag in other file somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cart page is loaded via customizable WordPress Page. Edit your page and check if the "HTML" editor tab content contains any "code" HTML tag.

If you cannot find this tag, you will need to check all actions executed with "woocommerce_before_cart" and "woocommerce_after_cart".